# How to change title in Material UI ToolBar on page navigation in react js web application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-context

I have react functional component MainToolBar. On navigation to other page (function component) I need to change the title of the MainToolBar. How could I do that ? Either with Context API or Redux or any other simple thing

Below is code for MainToolBar.Js

```
 export default function MainToolBar() {
 const classes = useStyles();
      return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <AppBar position="static">
             <Toolbar>
               <Typography align="center" variant="h6" className ={classes.title}>
                ERP System
               </Typography>
               <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
             </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Below is code for Thirdparty.js

```
function ThirdParty() {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>ThirdParty</label>            
    </div>
 )
}

export default ThirdParty;

 ****layout.js****

import {
  BrowserRouter as ReactRouter,
  Switch as ReactSwitch,
  Route as ReactRoute,
} from "react-router-dom";

import ThirdParty from "./ThirdParty.js";
    
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactRouter>
        <MainToolBar />
          <ReactSwitch>
          <ReactRoute exact path="/" component={SignInUp}> 
          </ReactRoute>         
          <ReactRoute exact path="/thirdparty" component= 
          {ThirdParty}></ReactRoute>
        </ReactSwitch>
      </ReactRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So let me rephrase it once again. You have a AppBar in which you have a heading called ERP System. Now if you go to some other route you want it to be changed according to the component. Am I correct ?

Comment: @dhellryder yes you got me right.... !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Context API` and `redux` are both good solution for this. This way, you can write a simple effect hook that will update toolbar title context / dispatch redux action that will change it. This hook will be called inside the main components that are rendered by the `Route` components.

Another solution, but might be less consistent, is to create a mapping object for optional toolbar titles based on paths. That way you can identify the path with the react-router-dom `useLocation` hook, and change the title in an effect. For example,

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const titles = {
  "/": "ERP System",
  "/thirdparty": "Third Party"
};

...
// Inside Toolbar component
const location = useLocation();
const [title, setTitle] = useState(titles["/"]);

useEffect(() => {
  setTitle(titles[location.pathname]);
}, [location.pathname]);

...
```

If you have paths that depend on ID values, more complex logic will be required inside the effect.

Comment: Thanks for answer and code !!  I would like to know which is better to use Redux or Context API

Comment: For my opinion, if you have already redux in your app, use redux. If not, simple context is enough.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhMKvyLRWo0 is good video for context api. Just for other newbie like me to help with this question.